# How to do a find replace around some function call

Tags: regex, replace, pycharm

I have a lot of calls in lots of different files to `os.getenv('some_var')`. I would like to replace all of these with `os.environ['some_var']`.

I know how to replace all instances of `os.getenv` with `os.environ` but not how to replace the `(.*)` with `[.*]` without loosing the text inside.

Comment: Can 'some_var' contain another set of parenthesis?

Comment: No, definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(os\.)[^()]*\(([^()]*)\)
```

Replace each match with `\1environ[\2]`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU3Eow/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `(os\.)` - matches `os.` and capture in group 1
- `[^()]*\(` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `(` nor `)` follwed by `(`
- `([^()]*)` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `(` nor `)`. This substring is captured in Group 2
- `\)` - matches `)`

Answer (score 1):

You can match the text and capture the text inside parenthesis using this regex,

```
os.getenv\('([^']+)'\)
```

And replace it with `os.environ['\1']`

This regex basically has three parts,

- `os.getenv\('` - This literally matches `os.getenv('`
- `([^']+)` - This captures whatever text is there in parenthesis and captures it in group1
- `'\)` - This literally matches `')`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kuz2PZ/1)**